# Dompdf: Get index of page-breaking table tr for arithmetic carry

Tags: php, css, twig, dompdf, invoice

I am using Dompdf to create invoices for an online shop.

If the list of articles exceed the available space on a page, it generates a page break and continues on the next page with a new `thead` as it is supposed to be.

What I need to do next is show an arithmetic carry (the sum of all previous articles) of the previous page(s) somewhere on top of the pages after a page break.

I am searching for a solution to find out the index of the `tr` after which a page break is produced.

I was thinking of attaching an invisible element with the current sum of all previous articles to each `tr` and then display only the correct elements according to the beaking `tr` elements' indices, but I don't know if this is the best way to do this.

Also I thought about css count which is working with Dompdf, but I wasn't able to find out whether I can make an element visible by the current number of a counter.

Just if it helps: I am generating the invoice document dynamically via Twig with an {{for ... in ... }} loop.

I appreciate any help! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "sum of all previous articles"? Is this the sum of a value in the table or just a count of the number of rows prior to the current row?

Comment: This is going to be the sum of the article prices since law requires to show the current amount of money on each page of the invoice here in Germany.